# Docker: Multiple Dockerfiles in project

Tags: docker

How do you organize the Dockerfiles belonging to a project when you have one Dockerfile for the database, one for the application server, and so on? Do you create some sort of hierachy in the source?
A big enterprise project can't consist of only one Dockerfile?

Comment: you may want to change the accepted answer

Comment: There should be an option to "outvote" and move automatically an obsolete `Accepted' attribute to a more appropriate answer. The eligibility criterion for such a move could be 1) a large difference in votes of say, 10:1 AND 2) the question author has not logged in for say, a year or longer (it seems @LuckyLuke has retired from SO 4 years ago...)

Comment: I want to update the question, but is already at 256, god help me

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Author's Note

**This answer is out of date.** Fig no longer exists and has been replaced by [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
Accepted answers cannot be deleted.

Docker Compose supports the building of project hierachy. So it's now easy to support a Dockerfile in each sub directory.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── project1
│   └── Dockerfile
└── project2
    └── Dockerfile
```

---

### Original answer

I just create a directory containing a Dockerfile for each component. Example:

- [Setting up a docker / fig Mesos environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217208/setting-up-a-docker-fig-mesos-environment/25218202#25218202)

When building the containers just give the directory name and Docker will select the correct Dockerfile.

Comment: @DuncanJones Cause you cannot delete an accepted answer... Tried :-)

Comment: The problem with this approach is if we need to add files from root directory to the project file while building the docker image it is a big problem.

Comment: I see your point, yes, changing a common file would mean all the images would to be rebuilt. 

Personally, I try to avoid multiple Dockerfile within a project. Where I encounter this scenario I build a single image that contains multiple binaries. At run-time the image can be invoked using different commands.

Comment: +1 for modifying the answer with the newer acceptable solution, a lot of people just leave depricated ways of doing things.

Answer (score 466):

In [newer versions(>=1.8.0) of docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki), you can do this

```bash
docker build -f Dockerfile.db .
docker build -f Dockerfile.web .
```

A big save.

EDIT: update versions per raksja's comment

EDIT: comment from @vsevolod: it's possible to get syntax highlighting in VS code by giving files .Dockerfile extension(instead of name) e.g. Prod.Dockerfile, Test.Dockerfile etc.

Comment: Just checked, https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki, so its > Docker 1.8.0

Comment: sure this works, but my IDE won't do any syntax highlighting though, because it doesn't recognized the filename :(

Comment: @AlexanderMills my IDE WebStorm doesn't even allow `Dockerfile.web` as a run configuration.  So I created an issue:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28185

Comment: How do you specify which Dockerfile should be used for each 'service' defined within a `docker-compose.yml` file, for example?

Comment: @AlexanderMills in IntelliJ IDEA you can associate filetype with a file name regex: Dockerfile.*

Comment: @JoeTidee A bit late to the party, but as stated in the docs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) you can use `dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate` inside of the `build` section for your container.

Comment: @AlexanderMills you could also name the files db.Dockerfile, web.Dockerfile, etc, then the intellisense would recognize them as dockerfiles

Comment: Seconding @DmitryTokarev's suggestion. Matching the Dockerfile type to Dockerfile* works great, and preserves syntax highlighting.

Comment: You can also just create directories like docker-prod or whatever you need and add a normally named Dockerfile to that directory, and then specify it with the path: `docker build -f ./docker-prod/Dockerfile`

Comment: From 2019 (or earlier) it's possible to get syntax highlighting in VS code by giving files .Dockerfile extension(instead of name) e.g. Prod.Dockerfile, Test.Dockerfile etc.

Comment: It doesn't work for `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`. I get `docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`, although `docker build --help` shows the `--file` option

Comment: I figured it it out: I still need to give the build context, which is a directory. So mind the dot at the end of `docker build -f tests/Dockerfile.pytest .`

Answer (score 273):

### Use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and multiple `Dockerfile` in separate directories

> **Don't rename your `Dockerfile`** to `Dockerfile.db` or `Dockerfile.web`, it may not be supported by your IDE and you will lose syntax highlighting.

As [Kingsley Uchnor said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837061/1092815), you can have multiple `Dockerfile`, one per directory, which represent something you want to build.

I like to have a `docker` folder which holds each applications and their configuration. Here's an example project folder hierarchy for a web application that has a database.

```
docker-compose.yml
docker
├── web
│   └── Dockerfile
└── db
    └── Dockerfile
```

`docker-compose.yml` example:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    # will build ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    build: ./docker/web
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  db:
    # will build ./docker/db/Dockerfile
    build: ./docker/db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  redis:
    # will use docker hub's redis prebuilt image from here:
    # https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

`docker-compose` command line usage example:

```bash
# The following command will create and start all containers in the background
# using docker-compose.yml from current directory
docker-compose up -d

# get help
docker-compose --help
```

### In case you need files from parent folder(s) as part of the build context of your Dockerfile

You can still use the above solution and place your `Dockerfile` in a directory such as `docker/web/Dockerfile`, all you need is to set the build `context` in your `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
```

The files hierarchy would loke like this:

```
config-on-root.ini
docker-compose.yml
docker
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── some-other-config.ini
```

The `./docker/web/Dockerfile` will have access to desired files from the context like this:

```docker
FROM alpine:latest

COPY config-on-root.ini /
COPY docker/web/some-other-config.ini /
```

Also note that the build context will contain all the files of the specified directory. Make sure tou use a `.dockerignore` file to prevent loading undesired large files or directories to save time during build.

[Here are some quick commands from tldr docker-compose](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/docker-compose.md). Make sure you refer to [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for more details.

Comment: What if you need to copy a package manager file in order to install deps on build time (f.i `COPY ../package.json /app/package.json`)? That file will be usually at root level and docker has forbidden access to the parent. What approach will you follow?

Comment: I've hit that limitation too and for this exception, I build the `web` project from `.`  (in `docker-compose.yml`: `build: .`). This way, `web` has access to root files when building. I've seen this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537340/docker-adding-a-file-from-a-parent-directory and we can build from parent directory instead when using `docker` command line and this answer shows how to do so with docker-compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353241/1092815

Comment: Right, I end up adding `.` as `context` in the `build` option so I can access those files at root. Thanks @GabLeRoux

Comment: This is an issue with your IDE, not with docker. @Shuo has the correct answer.

Comment: @BentOnCoding Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077543/how-to-name-dockerfiles

Comment: Second answer is 1 year old but it's not directly taken form Docker's documentation. `-f` option is fine, but I prefer to use `docker-compose` with subfolders. I think both answers are valid. Most people may just prefer to keep the default `Dockerfile` name to support most IDEs out of the box. I'm not invalidating first answer, I'm just providing an alternative. I just don't like my IDE to think my Dockerfile is a `php` file when I use `Dockerfile.php`, but yes, it works. I've seen a few examples in docker documentation; `Dockerfile.build`, `Dockerfile.debug`, etc.

Comment: Naming as `example.Dockerfile` keeps syntax highlighting and icons on VSCode.

Comment: This is a lot of complexity to add simply to get syntax highlighting in your IDE for what is a pretty trivial file format.

Comment: This is a really good answer.

Comment: "In case you need files from previous folders when building your Dockerfile" this part of the answer is not clear at all. It needs to be clarified.

Comment: @bit I’ve updated the answer to make it easier to understand. Let me know how I can improve the answer if you feel it’s still unclear :)

Answer (score 16):

In Intellij, I simply changed the name of the docker files to *.Dockerfile, and associated the file type *.Dockerfile to docker syntax.

Comment: Tried this and I get a nice Docker icon.

Comment: to build the docker image:  docker build . -f example.Dockerfile

Comment: I don't get it, if going with this solution, within Intellij all you have to do is right click a file "Override File Type" > Select Docker.

Answer (score 3):

Add an abstraction layer, for example, a YAML file like in this project https://github.com/larytet/dockerfile-generator which looks like

```yaml
centos7:
    base: centos:centos7
    packager: rpm
    install:
      - $build_essential_centos 
      - rpm-build
    run:
      - $get_release
    env:
      - $environment_vars
```

A short Python script/make can generate all Dockerfiles from the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

When working on a project that requires the use of multiple dockerfiles, simply create each dockerfile in a separate directory. For instance,

app/
db/

Each of the above directories will contain their dockerfile. When an application is being built, docker will search all directories and build all dockerfiles.