# Multiple dockerfiles in one docker or multiple images from one dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I saw [this question about multiple dockerfiles in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409761/multiple-dockerfiles-in-project):

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.db .
docker build -f Dockerfile.web .
```

What does this mean? Is it one dockerfile with different "tags" in it? (if yes, is it possible to show a short example?) Or there is two dockerfiles in the repository with the names *Dockerfile.db* and *Dockerfile.web*?

Comment: It doesn't follow the convention of docker best practice, not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different dockerfiles. One for the database. And the other with the webserver.

Comment: so this is a new solution to get 2 dockerfiles in the same repository?

Comment: You can have two dockerfiles in the same directory for building images. But i prefer having one dockerfile in a directory with additional needed files.

Comment: Thanks. when I have 2 dockerfiles, is it possible to perform the build like this: docker build -f Dockerfile.db -t localhost:5000/test/test-db:${version} . ?

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but i would say "Yes".