# Docker compose and external images multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I use [Docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), specifically:

> #### Use an external image as a “stage”
>
> When using multi-stage builds, you
>   are not limited to copying from stages you created earlier in your
>   Dockerfile. You can use the COPY --from instruction to copy from a
>   separate image, either using the local image name, a tag available
>   locally or on a Docker registry, or a tag ID. The Docker client pulls
>   the image if necessary and copies the artifact from there. The syntax
>   is:

In my case I have three Docker files.

One Dockerfile simply defines an image, which I use as a build stage to share among two other Dockerfiles:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

## do some heavy computation that will result in some files that I need to share in 2 Dockerfiles
```

and suppose that I build the above Dockerfile giving:

`docker build -t my-shared-build -f path/to/shared/Dockerfile .`

So now I have a `my-shared-build` image that I share between two containers, their dockerfiles look like:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# do something

COPY --from=my-shared-build some/big/folder /some/big/folder

CMD ["/my-process-one"]
```

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# do something

COPY --from=my-shared-build some/big/folder /some/big/folder

CMD ["/my-process-two"]
```

And I can build and run them.

So to recap, what I currently do is:

1) Build the shared image
2) Build the process one image
3) Build the process two image

now I can just run the "process one" and "process two" containers.

### Problem

Now I would like to use Docker Compose to automate the execution of "process one" and "process two".

So the question is: how can I specify in the Docker Compose that I need to **first** build the shared image and **then** build the other images (and then run their containers) ?

Comment: why don't just use a bash script?

Comment: @Siyu I thought it would be possible to achieve what I wanted just using docker compose...

Comment: docker-compose is an orchestration tool, not building tool, so you have to use tricks to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do that just fine.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    my-shared-build:
        image: my-shared-build:latest
        build: my-shared-build

    my-process-one:
        image: my-process-one:latest
        build: my-process-one
        depends_on:
            - my-shared-build

    my-process-two:
        image: my-process-two:latest
        build: my-process-two
        depends_on:
            - my-shared-build
            - my-process-one
```

Assuming your Dockerfiles are in subdirectories my-shared-build, my-process-one, my-process-two this should build all 3 images (in order)

Comment: then how does Docker Compose know that `my-shared-build` is NOT a real service and should not be launched as a container ?

Comment: That's a good question (that I didn't consider).  
I can think of a couple of ways:

    docker-compose up --scale my-shared-build=0   

or, create 2 compose files (build.yaml and docker-compose.yaml) - build.yaml contains the text provided above while docker-compose.yaml only contains my-process-one & my-process-two.

    docker-compose -f build.yaml build
    docker-compose up